# Manually run IOS UIEvent loop

Tags: ios, uiapplication, uievent

I am working on a project where I want to manually run the main event loop on IOS.  That is to say, I want to dequeue the UIEvents myself from the source, and then send them on to the UIApplication.

I have found examples on how to do this for OS X, and it works.  In that case, it is a matter of calling "nextEventMatchingMask" and then "sendEvent" on the NSApplication object.

However, I cannot find the equivalent means to gather events on IOS with a UIApplication object.  I have been reading about an "event queue", but I do not yet see how I could get a reference to this queue object.  Does anybody know how I could acquire UIEvents from the source, so that I can send them to the UIApplication?